# Função que retorna o nome do cliente usando o método .filter

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

No meu template possuo uma interpolação que realiza uma chamada pra função `getNomeCliente`, passando o `ClienteId` como parâmetro:

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  <div class="whole-cell">
    {{ getNomeCliente(dataItem.ClienteId) }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Preciso pesquisar o nome do cliente no meu array `clienteList` e retornar apenas o nome do cliente.

**Tentei algo como:**

```
  public getNomeCliente(clienteId: string): string{
    this.clienteList.filter((item) => {item.ClienteId.indexOf(clienteId) !== -1}).map((cliente) => { return cliente.ClienteNome});
  }
```

porém eu recebo no visual studio:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

Comment: Tá faltando um `return` aí, não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como é possível ver pelo erro, o problema é que `getNomeCliente` não é void, nem retorna qualquer coisa (any), logo, algo precisa ser retornado, nesse caso uma string. Fora isso, você pode utilizar o `find`, ao invés do `filter` e `map`. Segue exemplo:

```
public getNomeCliente(clienteId: string): string{
    return this.clienteList.find((item) => {item.ClienteId.indexOf(clienteId) !== -1}).ClienteNome;
}
```

Caso o `item.ClienteId` não seja um array, a melhor comparação seria comparar diretamente os Ids:

```
public getNomeCliente(clienteId: string): string{
    return this.clienteList.find((item) => (item.ClienteId === clienteId)).ClienteNome;
}
```

Abaixo temos um exemplo do uso do `find` com array de objetos complexos:

```js
const arr = [{a: 1, b:'errado'}, {a:2 , b:'certo'}];
console.log(arr.find(element => (element.a === 2)).b);
```

Comment: O find comparando os ids funcionou perfeitamente para o propósito esperado.